# nslookup with and without http points to different ips

Tags: domain-name-system, web-hosting, godaddy, dns-hosting, amazon-route53

I recently changed my registrar and transferred my DNS from Route 53 to Godaddy. Now, I cannot reach my website from any web browser.

nslookup and ping gives me correct ip if i do this.

```
nslookup
> www.example.com
```

but if I use http it points to some different ip.

```
nslookup
> http://www.example.com
```

What am I missing?

Comment: nslookup can't resolve URL's so I'd be curious to see the actual results of that lookup.

Comment: Provide the true names involved and use `dig` to troubleshoot DNS problems, not `nslookup`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the `nslookup http://www.example.com` *should* return a `NXDOMAIN` error.

However, some ISPs will return the IP of an ad server, a search server, etc. instead of a proper NXDOMAIN.

What service provider are you using? What DNS servers are you using?  What happens if you use a known-NX-issuing server for DNS requests?

I'll bet that if you try `nslookup http://www.example.com 8.8.8.8` (ie, ask Google's public server about http://...) you'll get a proper NXDOMAIN return.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was not aware of NXDOMAIN error. And turns out you were correct. I was getting same ip when I did nslookup somethingjibrish.com. And this was not the main source of my server being unreachable. Apparently the site was using load balancer when it was in Route 53, which I was not aware of. So when I moved this to godaddy I pointed directly to server where SSL certificate was not installed.